# Use Port Forwarding on Airport Extreme

Tags: port-forwarding, airport-extreme

Is there any way to use port forwarding on an Airport Extreme? I don't know the exact model but I know for a fact that it is the newest kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out that it will not work for me because my router (The Airport Extreme) is hooked up to another router which is then connected to the Internet. For this to work, I would need to have the Airport Extreme connected directly into the Internet.

Comment: Well, since that detail was not in your question, this doesn't really answer your question. But indeed: chaining routers might give [double-NAT issues](http://support.iprimus.com.au/index.php?Itemid=214&id=517&option=com_content&task=view), which can also be circumvented by putting the Extreme in bridging mode (something like "Connection Sharing: Off (Bridge Mode)").

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Click Manual Setup to get into the detailed config view, then click the Advanced category and select the Port Mapping tab. Click + at the bottom of the list, and type in the port & IP address info.

Comment: When I go to the Advanced category, I don't have a "Port Mapping" tab. I just have "Logging and Statistics", "MobileMe", and "IPv6".

Comment: Hm - what's your firmware and Airport Utility version?

Comment: You can also get to the Port Mapping screen from the Internet category: select the NAT tab then click Configure Port Mappings.

Comment: @martona: Airport Utility: 5.5.2. Firmware: 7.5.1

Comment: @martona: I don't have a "NAT" tab under the "Internet" category, either.

Comment: Well I'm on 5.5.1 with 7.5.1. Not sure what difference this makes. Have you tried the Internet -> Nat -> Configure Port Mappings route? What, if anything do you get on Internet -> Nat?

Comment: @martona: Maybe it would help if we were to continue this in the Super User chat. I'll be in the "Root Access" room.